# I am new to Tkinter python and I am having a problem with Top Level window creation using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

My question is about creating the TOP level windows based on the the if else condition from main window. I am working on a script to create top level windows based on user input and only the latest created TOP level window is working and the button in main window is frozen. I would like to have both the top level windows opened based on user input and the buttons on top level windows and on main window working. Can anyone help me where I am going wrong in this. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using Mac OS Bigsur Version 11.2.3 and Xcode version 12.4 editor for developing my scripts. Here is my code,

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *

window_main = tk.Tk()

window_main.title("Main Window")

def level1():

    print("Toplevel1 button works here")
    
def level2():

    print("Toplevel2 works here")
    
def main_window():

    a = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if a == 1:
        toplevel1 = tk.Toplevel(window_main)
        button_toplevel1 = tk.Button(toplevel1, text = 'Toplevel 1' ,command = level1)
        button_toplevel1.pack()
        
    elif a == 2:
        toplevel2 = tk.Toplevel(window_main)
        button_toplevel2 = tk.Button(toplevel2, text = 'Toplevel 2' ,command = level2)
        button_toplevel2.pack()
        
button_main_window = tk.Button(window_main, text = 'Generate Top Level windows',command = main_window)

button_main_window.pack()

window_main.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is frozen as long as you type some number onto terminal, this is because code after `input()` will not be executed as long as no input is entered at all, and hence `mainloop()` wont be able to update and causes the GUI to freeze.

Comment: You don't use `input` in a GUI application.  Instead, just create two buttons, one to create toplevel 1, one to create toplevel 2.

Comment: Also You don't use `print` (except maybe for debugging) in a GUI, normally a label is used, for input it is possible to use entry